# CSS: two, divs side-by-side

Tags: css, html, css-float

How can I make the green/yellow box be displayed next to the sidebar instead of below it?
The green/yellow part should be 100% width.

[image: Screensho]

Here is my sourcecode:
**HTML**

```
    <div id="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="header">

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar{
    background-color: #404040;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #808000;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `display:inline-block` to both `#sidebar` and `.header`

Answer (score 4):

Give this **CSS** code a try, I added a `float` property. You can also use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVY7T/7/) here, to see what I changed.
Also you want to have a look at the link and the tip (about clearing) that @Ian Clark provided in the comments:   [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

```
#sidebar{
    background-color: #404040;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #808000;
}
```

For more information about `float` check:

- [Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Comment: Any other google search would have done it too, yes. ;)

Comment: BTW I just looked at your code. You don't need the header to `float` have a `position` or a `width` [(See JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/AVY7T/7/)

Comment: You should also clear after your floats. Wrapping your floated elements in a container using the [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) is a nice option IMO

Comment: Strange, I'm pretty sure that i tried that. I would make an update, if it's ok for you. But you can answer the question as well.

Comment: Sure it's fine :) - I just got back from the cinema and wanted a little snoop. Not in the mood for a full post. Also, try to get in the habit of putting your fiddles at the top of your answers, easier for passers by to look at your work :)